# JDBC driver loading issue in JDBC connection pooling

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have setup the JDBC connection pooling and its showing the following error when I execute a sample JSP page trying to use a connection.

```
Error occurred org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load 
    JDBC driver class 'com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver'
```

I have placed the `jconn2.jar` both in `common/lib` and `web-inf/lib` as well.
How do I rectify the error?

```
    The context.xml

<Context>
        <Resource name="jdbc/mysybase" auth="Container"
                  type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver"
                  url="jdbc:sybase:Tds:H2S33.studtrack.com:2025/student"
                  username="scott" password="tiger" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
                  maxWait="-1"/>
    </Context>


    In The web.xml file
    <resource-ref>
     <description>Sybase Datasource example</description>
     <res-ref-name>jdbc/mysybase</res-ref-name>
     <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>


    And the jsp page

    <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
    <%@page import="javax.naming.Context"%>
    <%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
    <%@page import="javax.sql.DataSource"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Obtaining a Connection</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <%
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
         try {
           Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
           DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/mysybase");
           conn = ds.getConnection();
        if (conn != null) 
        {
            String message = "Got Connection " + conn.toString() + ", ";
            out.write(message);
        }
        else
        {
            out.write("hello no conn obtained");

        }

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Student");
        while(result.next())
        {
            out.write(result.getString("name"));
        }

         }
         catch (SQLException e) {
             out.write("Error occurred " + e);
          }

    %>

    </body>
    </html>`
```

Comment: Do you have all other relevant JAR files? such as commons dbcp, collections, pool in your lib ?

Comment: do you have full stacktrace? It should contain the root exception.

Comment: I have all these jar files in my common/lib.What else do i need aprt from the below mentioned. servlet-api.jar, naming-resources.jar, naming-factory-dbcp.jar, naming-factory.jar, jtds2.jar, jsp-api.jar ,jconn2.jar, jasper-runtime.jar, jasper-compiler-jdt.jar, jasper-compiler.jar, commons-el.jar.

Comment: Error occurred org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load      JDBC driver class 'com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver'  is all i get when i execute the jsp page.

Comment: Make sure there is `com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver` in your jconn2.jar and not `com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it was containing com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver class all along.Issue fixed.But how come any of my jsp/servlets were not throwing any errors/exceptions when i was using com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver as the driver to be loaded.

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe they did not access the database and tomcat dbcp loads the driver lazily? Posting an answer so you can close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sybase JDBC driver has different package naming in different versions. You are trying to load newer version `com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver`, while your jar most likely contains older `com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver`.

Comment: One last thing.This pooling is working for jsp/servlets.Will i be required to do any changes for the jdbc pooling to be available for normal java classes.